# Remove first 3 characters from title

Tags: jquery

I need to remove first 3 characters from title. I used:

```
$(".layered_subtitle").each(function() {
var text = $(this).text();
text = text.replace('06.', '');
$(this).text(text);
```

I have dynamicly loaded titles with numbering:

> 01.title
>
> 02.title
>
> 03.title ..

How to to separate characters to be removed?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use this (shortest of the `slice`/`substring`/`substr`-related JavaScript functions which are effectively the same if only using the first argument with a positive integer):

```
text = text.slice(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers so far are all right, but i think you should do it differently for future use. Maybe your count will extend, so just search for the first occurence of "." and then cut the string there.

```
text = text.substring(text.indexOf(".")+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [javascript substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) :

```
text = text.substring(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
text = text.substr(3);
alert(text);
$(this).text(text);
```

Comment: the second parameter is unnecessary

Comment: yah NimChimpsky.i considered "remove first 3 characters" as "otherthan first 3" sry for that

Answer (score 0):

You could use substring method like this:

```
$(".layered_subtitle").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if(text && text.length > 3){
        text = text.substring(3)
        $(this).text(text);
    }
});
```

If you need to do this on ajax request success:

```
function removeChars(){
   $(".layered_subtitle").each(function() {
       var text = $(this).text();
       if(text && text.length > 3){
           text = text.substring(3)
           $(this).text(text);
       }
   });
}
var serializedData = {};//Fill data
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: "post",//post or get
    data: serializedData,
    // callback handler that will be called on success
    success: function (){
        //Add here logic where you update DOM
        //(in your case add divs with layered_subtitle class)
        //Now there is new data on page where we need to remove chars
        removeChars();
    }
});
```

Comment: one more thing, function is not working after ajax call. At first it removes first 3 characters but after i use filter which loads content characters appears again :)

Comment: It is difficult to explain. I have eshop with product filter, in that filter i have titles with that numbers near every title. Code is working until i use filter because filter is using ajax to oload content. I tried .live in this function but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried using success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) jQuery event? When ajax call is success and when you update DOM then call this method.

Comment: unfortunately i have not enough knowledge to do that by my self :(

Comment: I updated my answer. Now on ajax success you update DOM and call removeChars method. Can you make it work with this?

Comment: thank you for your time. Unfortunately it is not working, but i think this is my fault. I will try different way to fix this situation.

Comment: You are welcome :).
But we still didn't solved the problem :(.
If you can post you code example maybe someone can help you with this problem.

Comment: I can explain why numbers appear.
I am using prestashop, there is no possibility to sort product features. So i found a sollution in prestashop forum to add numbers in front of every feature. like 01. 02. 03 and so on. And i need to hide those unnecessary characters. There is a code posted and it hides characters only in products but not in product filter which uses those features. Need to implement the same way to hide characters into filters control file. Here is a link to post: http://www.prestashop.com/forums/index.php?/topic/9709-edit-features-order-list/page__view__findpost__p__504198

Comment: And here is filters php file which controls everything:

http://jsfiddle.net/4yGK2/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
text = text.substring(3)
```

instead of

```
text = text.replace('06.', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the exact position of separator (point) you must find it:

```
var newText = oldText.substr(oldText.indexOf('.') + 1);
```

Or, if you can find many digits or a space char after separator you need to use a regex:

```
var newText = oldText.replace(/^\d+\.\s*/, "");
```

Both would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the first three characters, if the title is at least three characters:

```
if (text.length >= 3) text = test.substring(3);
```

You can use a regular expression to only remove the numbers if it matches the format "nn.xxxx":

```
 text = text.replace(/^\d\d\./, '');
```